# DNS doesn't resolve some domains on huge amount of requests

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-server, threads, multi-threading

I need to check 200kk (200,000,000) domains for availability and CMS information.

I'm using php 7.1 and simulating multi-thread check.

### Hardware and config

1. The server hardware: Multicore CPU, 64GB RAM, SSD disks, 500 Mbits dedicated bandwidth (OVH server).
2. In resolv.conf there are Google DNS: 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4
3. ulimit -n is set to 655350
4. nload to measure bandwidth load

### Tests

I have checked the first 1,000,000 domains from the database using a different amount of parallel threads. Once I did so I faced the problem, that with increasing number of threads the number of domains, that do not respond within 30 seconds timeout are highly increased. Here are the results.

**1. 1000 threads**

*TEST: 1,000,000 domains, 1000 parallel threads, 85 Mbits average bandwidth load, 1 hour check time.
RESULT: **65% where successfully resolved**, 35% were not resolved by timeout.*

**2. 300 threads**

*TEST: 1,000,000 domains, 300 parallel threads, 70 Mbits average bandwidth load, 2 hours check time.
RESULT: **85% where successfully resolved**, 15% were not resolved by timeout.*

### Summary

As we can see, with increasing the number of threads for 3 times, we do not get the bandwidth increase for 3 times more.
We got a huge increase of domains, that were not resolved\accessed by timeout. Thus the speed of check was increased 2 times more.

### The question

Where is the bottleneck of the check? How can I utilize the full 500 Mbits bandwidth? Should I use my own DNS server, and if so, what are the correct config for that?
Any ideas or help is highly appreciated.

### Update 1

> Google DNS is probably rate-limiting you. Using your own recursive DNS
>   resolver -- or several of them -- should be step 1.

I tried bind (DNS server) with its default configuration, without tuning it. I got HUGE bind load and the results were pretty the same.

Are there any ideas about how to tune bind to handle 200kk - 500kk requests per day? We can get another server just as a DNS server. Maybe we can use an alternative DNS server (not bind)?

Comment: Google DNS is probably rate-limiting you. Using your own recursive DNS resolver -- or several of them -- should be step 1.

Comment: Look at all metrics you have available from the OS and user space programs to find the bottleneck.  Start with the basics: https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/linux-performance-analysis-in-60-000-milliseconds-accc10403c55  Consider profiling your code and visualizing it:  https://daniellockyer.com/php-flame-graphs/   In this case, measure the request rates of DNS and HTTP.

Comment: "Maybe we can use an alternative DNS server (not bind)?" Look at unbound.